# batch, dealing with spaces in path

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

I have a CSV file with leading-and-trailing doublequotes per line I want to remove, and made a DOS batch to do it. The following works for an explicit path:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv) do (
    set line=%%A
    echo !line:~1,-1! >> C:\Folder\UnWrapped.csv
)
```

Of course, if the path has spaces in it, the following will not work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Folder\Sub Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv) do (
    set line=%%A
    echo !line:~1,-1! >> C:\Folder\Sub Folder\UnWrapped.csv
)
```

(`@echo on`, the message is "`...cannot find the file C:\Folder\Sub`", of course)

As a next-step test, I simply wrapped the two explicit filespecs in doublequotes:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\Folder\Sub Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv") do (
    set line=%%A
    echo !line:~1,-1! >> "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\UnWrapped.csv"
)
```

With `@echo on`, the `For` seems to be getting the correct filespec (original CSV), but now the destination CSV has

```
:\Folder\Sub Folder\EachLineWrappedInQuotes.cs
```

(the source CSV full filespec, with first and last characters removed), instead of the contents of the source CSV with first and last characters (the doublequote wrapping) removed.

Ultimately, I want to replace the explicit paths with a path variable like `%~dp0`, but haven't been able to get past the "next-step test".

(I have tried to solve this by studying the many answers already given, with no success, sorry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content of the file and remove double quotes, without the need to set variables, set `usebackq`

method 1:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\Folder\Sub Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv") do (
    echo %%~A >> "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\UnWrapped.csv"
)
```

method 2, if you still want to set the variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("C:\Folder\Sub Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv") do (
    set line=%%~A
    echo !line! >> "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\UnWrapped.csv"
)
```

Or by using `type` :

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('type "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\WrappedInQuotes.csv"') do (
    echo %%~A >> "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\UnWrapped.csv"
)
```